# window functions( lag) implementation and the use of IsNotIn in pyspark

Tags: t-sql, pyspark, window, apache-spark-sql, lag

Below is the T-SQL code attached. I tried to convert it to pyspark using window functions which is also attached.

```
  case 
             when eventaction = 'OUT' and lag(eventaction,1) over (PARTITION BY barcode order by barcode,eventdate,transactionid) <> 'IN'  
                  then 'TYPE4'
             else ''
      end as TYPE_FLAG,
```

Pyspark code giving error using window function `lag`

```py
Tgt_df = Tgt_df.withColumn(
    'TYPE_FLAG',
    F.when(
        (F.col('eventaction')=='OUT')
        &(F.lag('eventaction',1).over(w).isNotIn(['IN'])),
    "TYPE4"
).otherwise(''))
```

But it's not working. What to do!?

Comment: What is not working ? Can you show some sample data, expected output and error message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is giving you an error because there is no `isNotIn` method for columns object. 
That would have been obvious if you just posted the error message...

Instead, use the `~` (not) operator.

```
&( ~ F.lag('eventaction',1).over(w).isin(['IN'])),
```

List of available methods are in the [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column).